# Difference in the use of scopes in Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I use Dagger 2 to perform Dependency Inversion rule in my app. I was just looking on [Clean Architecture example by Fernando Cejas](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture/blob/7339de70e1d691b8f24b9ca0472536dc24838b96/data/src/main/java/com/fernandocejas/android10/sample/data/repository/datasource/UserDataStoreFactory.java) and I had a question - what is difference between the two approaches presented below:

If I mark the class like so:

```
@Singleton // or @PerActivity or @PerFragment, nevermind
public class UserDataStoreFactory {

  private final Context context;
  private final UserCache 
}
```

Or if I create a module, where I define a provide-method and add this module into the any component (PerActivity, PerFragment and so on, nevermind)

```
@Module
public class SomeModule {
     @Provides
     @Singleton  // or @PerActivity or @PerFragment, nevermind
     UserDataStoreFactory providesUserDataStoreFactory (Context context, UserCache userCache) {
          return new UserDataStoreFactory(context, userCache)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The two approaches are the same: Both will allow your UserDataStoreFactory to be injected throughout your application in the Singleton (or @PerActivity/@PerFragment/nevermind) scope.

The former approach, marking the class with the scope, will only work if the class has an @Inject-annotated constructor. The second approach does not require that constructor annotation, but does also require additional boilerplate code that is subject to change when the constructor arguments change. This makes the first approach more resilient to dependency changes on UserDataStoreFactory, even though they both achieve the same end result in your graph; however, the first approach may only be possible if the class is code you can change, or that is otherwise structured for scoped dependency injection.

Comment: Excuse me I didn't quite understand what do you mean by "...or that is otherwise structured for scoped dependency injection"? Could you please provide an example please?

Comment: You don't need a Module if your class has an @Inject constructor and any scopes you need, which means you need to have enough control to add those annotations, or that someone else will have added them for you already. That's all I meant.

Comment: But what about qualifiers?  Is it possible to use @Named annotation with constructor injected classes?

Comment: No, as of right now `@Inject`-constructed objects [may not have a qualifier](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/645657a691f6908a20718890b07fa8c8f4f68193/compiler/src/main/java/dagger/internal/codegen/ProvisionBinding.java#L147), so I suppose that is a difference between the two (even if it's unrelated to the scopes you'd asked about). Otherwise it might be pretty confusing for a class with an `@Inject`-annotated constructor to be unavailable when requesting an unqualified injection!